# Программное затемнение картинки

Tags: javascript, html, css, изображения

Как понять, как стиль или правило применяется к картинке на сайте, с помощью которого она как бы тонируется, затемняется. Хочу убрать это.

Сама картинка [светлая](http://teplo-ok.ru//assets/template/img/intro.jpg), а вот  когда [добавляю на сайт](http://teplo-ok.ru/) что то срабатывает, как это можно найти и убрать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main.css 95 строка

```css
.over-slide {
    background-color: rgba(65,74,82,0.45); - вот это вызывает затемнение 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

можете сделать так :

```
background-color: rgba(65,74,82,0);
```

или вообще удалить эту строку и будет такой результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]